# How to evaluate to false if one file is missing from a list of files

Tags: c#

I am trying to check a folder for a bunch of different files. I have added the files to a list and looped through.
The problem is I do not know how to evaluate to false if one of the files is missing.

I need the bool to evaluate to true only if all files are present.

```
    static List<string> files = new List<string>();
    static bool fileExists;
    static string Dir = @"Z:\MyDir\myFolder\";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        files.Add("MyFile1.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile2.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile3.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile4.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile5.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile6.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile7.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile8.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile9.txt");
        files.Add("MyFile10.txt");

        foreach(string fl in files)
        {
            fileExists = (File.Exists(Dir + fl));   
        }
```

Comment: As a side note, it's best to use `Path.Combine` when joining file paths.

Comment: Just a question, it is not possible to test the file existence just when you add it to the list?

Comment: Thanks everyone, love the `Path.Combine` very helpful info here. I wish I could mark multiple answers but these are all great. Thanks my friends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Linq solutions, but this is for the lovers of the old school....

```
    fileExists = true;
    foreach(string fl in files)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Dir,fl)))
        {
           fileExists = false;
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, love that this breaks out rather then continuing post evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

One-liner with LINQ, no need for a loop (**edit** use `Path.Combine`):

```
fileExists = files.All(fl => File.Exists(Path.Combine(Dir, fl)));
```

Comment: Instead of `Dir+fl`: `Path.Combine(Dir, fl)`

Comment: Love the LINQ solution but I am a bit orthodox and conventional, this is still extremely useful and thank you very much. I am going to book mark this.

Comment: You noted on @Steve's accepted answer that you like the `break`. As a follow up/FYI, this method also breaks early if any files don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them:

```
static bool fileExists = true;
...
...
foreach(string fl in files)
    {
        fileExists = fileExists && (File.Exists(Dir + fl));   
    }
```

Comment: Fine, but if a missing file is found the loop continue until the end (and if the file list is huge...)

Comment: That's right, but he may want to do other things then just check if it exists. If not, he should break when fileExists evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Default fileExists to true, and in your foreach if you find that a file does not exist then set it to false and break out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

For each successful file found, increment a counter:

```
static bool fileExists = false;
int fileCount = 0;
foreach(string fl in files)
    {
        if(File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Dir,fl)))
        {
           fileCount++;
        }
    }
if (fileCount == files.Count)
    {
        fileExists = true;
    }
```